# How to retrieve sms date field in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm new to Android programming and I was writing some test code to retrieve all the sms messages in the inbox using an sms intent. The code I wrote is as follows:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{"address","person","date","body"}, null, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();
if(c.getCount() > 0){
        while(!c.isLast()){
            System.out.println(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
}
```

Is this the right way?
I see that the  value  for the date column is retrieved as something like "1326781012725".
I want to convert this into a readable format like YYYY-MM-DD.How can I do this?

Note that I'm using API version 10 and hence the api - cursor.getType() (that returns the data type of the column) is not available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"1326781012725" is a timestamp. timestamp conversion can be made like this;

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date date = cal.getTime();
mHour = date.getHours();
mMinute = date.getMinutes();
```

Comment: Thank you. However I see that the date.getHours(), date.getMinutes() etc (and most other utility methods in Date class) are deprecated now. [link] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

Comment: Okay, I got it. I used SimpleDateFormat class to format the date object returned by cal.getTime() !

Comment: Sorry, I still haven't got the hang of formatting in stackoverflow, hence my posts/comments are not correctly formatted.